# Find volume of body bounded by surfaces $z=x^2+y^2$, $z^2=xy$ by triple integral

Tags: calculus, integration

How I can solve this problem? I know that i can use cylindrical coordinates, but what should be limitations of $r$ (radius) and $\varphi$ (angle)?

Comment: It is not duplicate, in this Q one surface is $z=x^2+y^2$.

Comment: $~x,y~$ must both be either non-negative or non-positive (i.e. they can't have
different signs).  Further, since $~(x - y)^2 \geq 0,~$ you know that 
$~(x^2 + y^2) \geq 2xy \geq xy.~$  So, you must have that $~z \geq 0,~$ and that
$~z \geq z^2 \implies ~z \leq 1.~$  This implies that $~x^2 + y^2 \leq 1.~$  Are
you sure that integration with polar coordinates rather than cartesian coordinates
is required?

Comment: Your posting is missing several details.
Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Comment: You need to find the intersection of these surfaces. The volume is equal two times the volume of part of the body for which $x,y\ge 0.$ It is not hard to find the intersection: $r=\sqrt{\sin\theta\cos\theta}.$ So $0\le r\le 2^{-1/2}$ and $0\le \theta\le \pi/2.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I am ignorant in this area.  Would integration by polar coordinates result in a *triple integral*?  Also, for a student new to or confused by the topic, is integration by Cartesian coordinates easier to understand than integration by polar coordinates?

Comment: @user2661923 Nobody suggested the polar coordinates. Cylindrical coordinates are appropriate (see OP), and they are applied in my previous comment.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Interesting response.  Goes to show that I am ignorant in this area.

Comment: @user2661923 You are not ignorant, as you observed that the polar coordinates in three dimensional space are inappropriate for this particular body. The Cartesian coordinates could be used, but if one encounters $x^2+y^2$ and $xy$ it is hard to resist from applying the cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: I didn't say that cylindrical coordinates are required, i just thought that it will make easier to solve this, but no, and for Cartesian coordinates I cant't find limitation of x,y and z

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Interesting.  I found [this article on Cylindrical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system) which may help the original poster.

Comment: "I can't find limitation of x,y, and z." : Please see the very first comment that I left, after your posting.

Comment: The volume is given by $$2\int\limits_0^{\pi\over 2}\int\limits_0^{\sqrt{\sin\theta\cos\theta}}r(r\sqrt{\sin\theta\cos\theta}-r^2)\,dr\,d\theta$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The volume is given by
$2\int\limits_0^{\pi\over2}\int\limits_0^{\sqrt{\sin\theta\cos\theta}}r(r\sqrt{\sin\theta\cos\theta}-r^2)\,dr\,d\theta$
Thank you Ryszard Szwarc